# Заголовок spinner

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос: как сделать что бы заголовок spinner отличался от выбранного значения, т.е. есть  список:

```
ПН 08:00-23:00
ВТ 09:00-23:00
СР 10:00-23:00
ЧТ 11:00-23:00
ПТ 12:00-23:00
СБ 13:00-23:00
ВС 14:00-23:00
```

И при выборе, например, `ВТ 09:00-23:00`, в сложенном состоянии у spinner был заголовок `09:00-23:00`
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вроде бы в адаптере есть два метода для рендера. Один, вроде, за элемент выпадающего списка отвечает, а второй за свёрнутое состояние. Вот в этих местах, по идее, и можно настроить разное отображение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, после 2 версии Android убрали этот метод setPrompt()

Comment: Признаться, я не понял что вы хотите сказать вашим комментрием. Про такой метод не слышал и его не имел в виду.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я думал вы этот метод имели ввиду, вот и указал что его больше нет

Comment: Нет, я не про него. Я лишь высказал предположение о том как можно это сделать через адаптер, если я правильно помню что там есть и как оно работает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю с чего вы решили что `setPrompt()` убрали. Этот метод есть и вроде как не deprecated. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setPrompt(java.lang.CharSequence)) например документация есть по нему, и там не указано что он устарел или его убрали. Касательно вашей задачи я думаю все более чем понятно: при выборе пункта меню спиннера указываем "урезанную" версию того что выбрано. Если же вам нужно как-то иначе сделать выбор спиннера, то вот есть например [статья](https://mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) где приведен довольно интересный вариант реализации. Вот еще [статья](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-spinner-prompt.html) и [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877114/is-there-no-prompt-in-the-android-4-x-spinner-anymore) на enSO. Но метод `setPrompt()` насколько я знаю сделан для того чтобы задавать заголовок диалогового окна. Если же вам нужно менять отображаемый элемент при закрытом виджете, то я вам советую использовать:

```
spinner.setSelection(index)
```

здесь вы будете указывать выбранный элемент из списка, вернее его индекс. Но суть данного решения в том что у вас будет отображен элемент списка полностью, а не так как вы хотите его изменить.